# Workflow and issue statuses in JIRA with a Scrum mode

Tags: jira, agile, scrum

Currently working with JIRA 5, I was looking for information about the handling Scrum in JIRA 6 with JIRA Agile (formerly Greenhopper). I saw, the there is now 3 statuses: *To Do*, *In Progress*, *Done*.

I find the 3 above statuses not enough. Particulary, we want to know if a story is still beeing clarified with the project owner, if is it a draft, if it has been approved by the customer. For a task, we also want to differenciate different steps in the "done" process: development done, review done, testing done, etc.

I'm looking for experience or any hints about this. My questions are: should I customize the workflow for my needs? Is there any standard workflows which already better supports Scrum? am I completly wrong and should I only use the basic concepts of JIRA for a Scrum process?

Any ideas/hints/experiences/links are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the JIRA workflow (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Workflow) and then map the new statuses into Agile columns

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I expected a more detailed answer. Actually the simplified workflow is very simple. Is there perhaps a better workflow available?

Answer (score 1):

In case if you already have a configured workflow go to your Agile board, go to its configuration and navigate to tab "Columns". On this screen you can add your custom column name, change its position and drag&drop status to a new column in order to map issues with this status to a column. If you use standard flow and need more customized one which better fits to your process then the link provided by mdoar above explains how to do this in details.